# Flutter: YouTube player/WebView leaves a ghost border/pixel bleed when placed in a stack underneath another card

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to put youtube players in a stack. It seems that when a player is placed in second position of the stack, the content is hidden as expected but a thin "ghost" border still shows up over the first card. Interestingly, this only shows up on a physical device (not in simulator) and when I take a screenshot the "ghost" border is not there. Here is a simple code mock-up of the situation:

Any ideas what could this be?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Positioned(left: 0,
              top: 100,
              child: Transform.scale(child: SimpleCard(), scale: 0.8)),
          Positioned(left: 0,
              top: 0,
              child: Transform.scale(child: SimpleCard(), scale: 1))
        ]
    );
  }
    
class SimpleCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const SimpleCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SimpleCard> createState() => _SimpleCardState();
}

class _SimpleCardState extends State<SimpleCard> {
  @override

  late YoutubePlayerController youtubeController;
  late Widget youtubePlayer;

  YoutubePlayerFlags playerFlags = const YoutubePlayerFlags(
    hideThumbnail: true,
    autoPlay: false,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    youtubeController = YoutubePlayerController(initialVideoId: "9bZkp7q19f0", flags: playerFlags);

    youtubePlayer = YoutubePlayer(
      controller: youtubeController,
      showVideoProgressIndicator: false,
      actionsPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      onReady: () {  },
    );

  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        height: 500,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(child: youtubePlayer, width: 300, height: 240),
                ]


              )

            ])
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the second player supposed to completely hide the first player underneath? Just wondering, why not try just showing the second player on it's own

Comment: It's a tinder like interface with draggable cards so I need both players visible when the user starts dragging the top card.